# What is the format of mtr raw output?

Tags: bash, mtr

I use mtr to count number of hops to a host and pass that number to a script.
I discovered `-l` (or `--raw`) option which produces an output ready for parsing. However, I'd like to know where to find this raw format description? Unfortunately, `man` and google give me only this:

```
-l

   --raw
          Use  this option to tell mtr to use the raw output format. This format is better suited for archival of the measure‐
          ment results. It could be parsed to be presented into any of the other display methods.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In their source files MTR has file named: FORMATS

[source](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr/blob/master/FORMATS)

From that file is the excerpt:

```
The "raw" format is:

hostline|xmitline|pingline|dnsline|timestampline|mplsline

hostline:
h <pos> <host IP>

xmitline:
x <pos> <seqnum>

pingline:
p <pos> <pingtime (ms)> <seqnum>

dnsline: 
d <pos> <hostname>

timestampline:
t <pos> <pingtime> <timestamp>

mplsline:
m <pos> <label> <traffic_class> <bottom_stack> <ttl>
```

When parsing this <pos> is an integer for the index of the host. The host at the first hop will be 0, second hop 1, etc. It should also be noted that pingtime is in ms, but microseconds and not miliseconds.